# What is the need of logging configuration in both wildfly and war file

Tags: logging, log4j, wildfly, slf4j

I am using wildfly as my application server. It has its own logging subsystem configured in standalone.xml file. Then what is the need for logging configuration in our application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends, but generally I would say there is no need for the logging configuration in your application. If you don't need any special handlers then there is actually an advantage to using the logging subsystem in WildFly.

If you use the web console, WildFly's CLI tool or some other form of management for WildFly then you can configure logging without having to restart the server or re-deploying your application. On the contrary if you include a logging configuration in your application and want to make a change you need to re-deploy your application.

Comment: If we use the configuration in both, what configuration will get the highest preference?

Comment: You can only have one log manager configure your logging so if you include a configuration in your deployment and/or a log manager then that will configure logging for your deployment. Otherwise logging for the server AND your deployment is done via the logging subsystem.